# is there any timeout for a lambdaInvoker using swift SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-lambda

I have a lambdaInvoker which seems to hang when I am connected to a network but the connection is not active.  For example when you connect to a network but have not authenticated yet.  So the wifi connection is on and connected but you have not validated yet.

When the wifi/cellular is off the function immediately returns the error you would expect.

In this case my function seems to run continuously with no callback.

Is there anyway to manually set a timeout for the invoker?

```
let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()

lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction(lambdaFunctionString, jsonObject: jsonObject).continueWith(block: {(task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
    if let error = task.error as NSError? {
        print(task.error!.localizedDescription)
        print(task.error!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if (error.domain == AWSLambdaInvokerErrorDomain) && (AWSLambdaInvokerErrorType.functionError == AWSLambdaInvokerErrorType(rawValue: error.code)) {
                print("Function error: \(String(describing: error.userInfo[AWSLambdaInvokerFunctionErrorKey]))")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
            }
        })
        return nil
    }
    // Handle response in task.result
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if let jsonArray = task.result as? NSArray {
            completion(jsonArray)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
    return nil
})
```